# Push or Commit from a git user account different from the global user account without SSH

Tags: git, github

I want to use two github user accounts on my computer. I already have the global user settings configured through the commands

```
git config --global user.name primary_username
```

and

`git config --global user.email primary_email`

Now I have a repository temp_repository for which I want to use the another account.
So I used the following commands to set the local configuration for that repository only:

```
git config user.name secondary_username
```

and

```
git config user.email secondary_email
```

But when I try to do an initial push using the command 'git push -u origin master', I get this error:

> remote: Permission to temp_repository denied to primary_username.
>   fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/secondary_username/temp_repository.git': The requested URL returned error: 403

Even after setting the configuration for the local repository separately, I get this error.
I don't want to use SSH keys since I think that I will be using this account only temporarily.

Comment: The thing is that in order to be able to push into github you _need_ to set up ssh certificates.

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/

Comment: I can do it without ssh too right? Because I haven't set up any ssh keys yet in my pc.

Comment: I might be wrong..... but I don't think so.

Comment: Yes you can do it without ssh you will just need to enter your password every time you push. You probably need to add the second account as a [collaborator](https://help.github.com/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/) to the repository since it's not the owner of the repo and doesn't have push access

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to give push access to the primary_username. I want to push it from the secondary_username instead. @SoZettaSho

Comment: Sorry, I misread. I thought the repo was owned by the primary account. Can you try setting the remote url to `https://secondary_username@github.com/secondary_username/temp_repository.git` and see if that helps?

Comment: No luck, it still gives the same error. @SoZettaSho

Comment: weird. all i can say is check the .git/config file in the local repo to make sure your credentials and all the URLs are set/spelled properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a very typical error, you confuse your commit identity with your push identity. What you configure with `user.name` and `user.email` is solely used when creating commits. Which identity is used for a commit has nothing to do with as whom you push stuff.

Please refer to https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials for how to configure the push identity that is used when pushing via https.

Comment: The link you suggested details on how git will store my credentials. I didn't found anything such as a 'push identity' on the link. Neither did I found the words 'push' and 'identity' individually when I did a find (Ctrl+F) on the webpage.

Comment: According to the above, if I don't make git store my credentials git will ask me for them as the page mentions (but it doesn't). Can you please help me figure out what to do. @Vampire

Comment: The whole page is about push / fetch credentials. As your primary username is used, you obviously **did** store your credentials before in the configured `credential.helper`, probably when you first cloned and it asked for your credentials. Use the info on that page to configure your secondary user for that repository and I'd expect you will be asked for the password by your credential helper.